# Strange lambda Expression breaks down IIS

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, iqueryable

I do a query with an `IQueryable<T>` on an `Entity.DbSet`. When I insert this line of code:

```
query = 
     query.Where(x => x.VersionInt == query.Max(y => y.VersionInt))
```

The whole IIS breaks down when I compile and run with this line. If I remove it everything is allright. What's happening?

Comment: "IIS breaks down" is not very descriptive. Is there some kind of error code?

Comment: too vague. you may have querying millions of raws, so finding Max cost a  lot

Comment: Try changing this to `var v = query.Max(y => y.VersionInt); query = query.Where(x => x.VersionInt == v);` Does that fix it?

Comment: Looks like some kind of infinite loop to me - you have a lot of calls to query there...can't quite figure out what it is doing!

Comment: @p.s.w.g when he means "breakdown", I guess that is just "process crashing, no log, no exception" ... which is either a low level native exception or a stack overflow exception (see my answer)

Comment: fyi - thts the whole stement -> the groupby heals everything: query = query.GroupBy(a => a.Nr).SelectMany(c => c.Where(y => y.VersionInt == c.Max(d => d.VersionInt)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack overflow exception (which will make the process crash - you cannot catch a StackOverflowException)!

Linq is lazy evaluated. Thus, your query is querying itself.

Did you meant

```
var querycopy = query;
query = query.Where(x => x.VersionInt == querycopy.Max(y => y.VersionInt))
```

or as oerkelens suggested, putting the "Max" evaluation outside of the Where would be even more performant.

Comment: Yes, my money here,  Recursion, causes stackoverflow. Which takes the APP POOL out.

Comment: You are still hoping that querycopy does get evaluated before the next line... it might very well not. 
Best case, you are copying a possibly huge IEnumerable when you only need one VersionInt.

Comment: @oerkelens copying an enumerable costs nothing. enumerating it is expensive, though... I know that my correction is still O(n^2) and I edited my answer accordingly. But I kept it that way to illustrate the issue.

Comment: StackOverflow was the answer - the x.VersionInt thing is just piece, i only wanted to know whats happening ... i know what i'm looking for ;-)

Comment: @Olivier: actually, Linq is smart enough to only enumerate the list twice if you use `query.Where(x => x.VersionInt == query.Max(y => y.VersionInt))` - it's not O(N^2) at all.

Comment: fyi - thts the whole stement -> the groupby heals everything:  query = query.GroupBy(a => a.Nr).SelectMany(c => c.Where(y => y.VersionInt == c.Max(d => d.VersionInt)))

Comment: and yes - the group by exactly does what u suggested ;-)

Comment: @DanPuzey I have kind of a doubt... are you sure ? a reference would be appreciated. Uncompiling Enumerable.Max does not seems to indicate so, and I dont see how this would be achieved technically. (we're speaking about linq-to-objects, not linq-to-entities => no expression analysis at play)

Comment: Well, I can tell you what I did, at least: using Linqpad, I created a test where the `IEnumerable` was provided by a method using `yield return`, with a message logged whenever the enumeration was started. With the original code, I got an infinite list of the message, followed by the `StackOverflowException`. When I switched the code to assign the result of the query to a new variable, I only saw the message twice. I know that some enumerables track a "version" internally to indicate whether the enumeration has been invalidated; maybe the Linq methods use that version to optimise methods.

Answer (score 2):

Simply find the max(VersionInt) first before querying

```
var maxVersion = query.Max(x => x.VersionInt);
query = query.Where(x => x.VersionInt == maxVersion);
```

Comment: fyi - thts the whole stement -> the groupby heals everything: query = query.GroupBy(a => a.Nr).SelectMany(c => c.Where(y => y.VersionInt == c.Max(d => d.VersionInt)))